# Efficiently regulating primary cells for a long-life IoT device

Tags: power-supply, batteries, voltage-regulator

I'm working on a long-life IoT sensor device which spends probably about 99.99% of its life asleep, waking up every 15 mins to take measurements and send data. I'm sure this is a problem that many people face as IoT becomes more popular.

I've figured out a few things to start: To get the longevity I require from the system the sleep mode current has to be tiny. Combined with this the primary cell has to be a high-capacity, low-self-discharge cell (Lithium Thionyl Chloride 3.6V battery, for example).

For example's sake, lets say the current requirements are typical of my typical wireless IoT device varying as follows, depending on the mode of operation over a period of 15 minutes:

- Sleep mode: <10uA (99.99% of the time)
- Measurement mode: 0.5-10mA (~10s)
- Transmission mode: up to 50mA (2-5s)

Ideally I'd power the device straight from the cell, but a couple parts I'm using have a max input voltage of 3.6V, and a few LiSOCl2 cells I've seen will sit at 3.7V before settling into their nominal voltage of 3.6V.

I'm aware the cell voltage may droop when under heavier load, so to be safe, 3V seems like a reasonable level to operate without being affected by the droop.

What is the best way to go about efficiently regulating this sort of primary cell to provide around 3V? The regulator would also have to consume very little current itself.

Comment: There's a lot of microcontrollers that surpass your specs by a solid amount.  There's also microcontrollers that include RF / networking functionality. Many of those also have a wide input voltage range, so I'm not convinced your question is overly specific - what MCU did you have in mind? Generally, your application describes what would usually be done with an LDO, but I really don't think one would generally be necessary.

Comment: What battery lifetime are you wanting? Unless you want 5 - 10 year range you probably do not need LTC cell.

Comment: is the mcu that sleeps/wakes a 3.7v tolerant part? If so, you can enable an LDO with one of its outputs for measurement/transmission, so as not to waste an LDO's bias current when you don't need to. Look for one with a vanishingly small disabled current.

Comment: @Neil_UK, that's a great idea, didn't think of that. The MCU (CC1310) can take up to 3.8V so it should work. Are LDO's similar in efficiency to buck converters?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I am aiming for that sort of lifespan (>7 years) which is why I selected the LTC cell.

Comment: No, LDOs burn the excess voltage as heat, and waste a little bit of bias current. Buck converters waste a bit of the power, but can put out more current than they take in if the voltage drop is large enough. When there's only a very small voltage to drop, an LDO can be as efficient as a buck, and simpler. You will still need to trawl specifications for near zero disable current.

Comment: I've had a quick look on analog.com, and their linear regulator table can have an Is(shutdown) parameter added to it, and be sorted on it. There are half a dozen at <= 10nA, and more <= 100nA, so it looks like they exist.

Comment: How far to the receiver it has to communicate with? How long of a life are you hoping to get? Is that 7 years?? Have you looked up the ambient backscatter method for communication, yet?

Comment: @jonk, The receiver will be less than 20 meters away. It's a residential application so not much further than a medium sized home. And yes, 7+ years is the target. Just looked into Ambient backscatter. Looks really cool, but maybe a little too undeveloped/limited for this project.

Comment: @Sensors Okay. It looks like you are facing a battery capable of providing about \$400\:\textrm{kJ}\$ or better over your period of time. Just a cursory look suggests that a D cell of the technology you mentioned provides well less than half that much. I didn't look into the self-discharge, though, but that only makes the situation still worse. Your transmitter is the big problem, which is why I suggested another idea. It's range is significantly less than 20 m, though. I'd recommend focusing on that part of it and getting that need DOWN. The regulator isn't the problem.

Comment: @jonk, I appreciate the suggestion, it's certainly cool tech and I'll keep an eye on it. 
The figures I gave were very vague and generalised for an IoT device on purpose so as to make the question more beneficial to the wider community.
I just came here looking for some advice on how to most efficiently regulate a LTC primary cell for a 'typical' IoT application, which I'm sure many others will have tried, or will try, to do. My actual application has an average current of about 70-100uA.

Comment: @Sensors Combined with the energy harvesting and fancy hybrid battery-capacitor devices (neither battery nor capacitor, but really an interesting cross-breed), ambient backscatter can be completely and permanently self-powered. You can bury them into ceramic tiles and make a floor out of them and never worry after. (There is a need for a "translation" that picks up nearby ambient backscatter coms and translates that into wifi or whatever. But just one can do.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, you're worrying about overvoltage.

I've never designed something like you're doing, but I wanted to focus your attention on something you could have forgotten: temperature. Temperature is something that has a tendency to behave like its other name is Murphy.

I know nothing about Lithium Thionyl Chloride, so I googled it, clicked on the first link, then clicked on a random datasheet for a random cell...

And whaddyaknow, the open circuit voltage rises with temperature at an alarming rate.

Will your stuff be exposed to direct sunlight?...

I would advise using a high-current CMOS micropower LDO.

High current, because you want the pass device to be enormous, so its dropout voltage is tiny under load.

CMOS and micropower, because idle current isn't your friend.